# What is the difference between `Add members to group` vs `Share site only`?

Tags: sharepoint-online

When I click on the gear icon, and site permissions, then there is a popup pane on right hand side.

Here when I click `Add members` I get two options:

1. Add members to group
2. Share site only

What's the difference between these two?

Answer (score 0):

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/modern-experience-sharing-permissions

When you add members to a group, the users permissions will be determined by the group you add them to.

When you share site only is useful to give someone access to the site without giving them the additional permissions that come with group membership.

Comment: But when I give someone access to site, then does it mean the user becomes owner, or memeber or visitor?

Comment: No, you can choose when granting permissions, whether to grant specific permissions or add them to a group.